# Create non editable block with text in CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How do I Create a non editable block with text in CKEditor 5.

I need something which in the final view generate a:

```
<div>Non editable message here</div>
```

I tried to use a UIElement and then set innerHTML but that still makes the element editable.

Just for reference: Her is the plugin I ended up using.

```
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled/src/decouplededitor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';
import imageIcon from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/image.svg';
import Command from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/command';
import { downcastElementToElement,downcastAttributeToAttribute,downcastAttributeToElement } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/downcast-converters';
import { upcastElementToElement, upcastAttributeToAttribute,modelToViewAttributeConverter} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/upcast-converters';
import attachPlaceholder from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/placeholder";
import ViewPosition from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/position';
import toWidgetEditable from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/utils';
import ClickObserver from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/observer/clickobserver';
import UpcastDispatcher from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/upcastdispatcher'; 
import { toWidget } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/utils';

export default class TestWidget2 extends Plugin {
    static get pluginName() {
        return 'TestWidget2';
    }

    init() {
        console.log('TestWidget2::init()');
        const editor=this.editor;
        const model=editor.model;

        model.schema.register( 'myWidget', {
            inheritAllFrom: '$block',
            isObject: true
        } );

        editor.conversion.for( 'dataDowncast' )
            .add( downcastElementToElement( {
                model: 'myWidget',
                view: ( modelItem, writer ) => {
                    const elm=writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'widget' } );
                    return toWidget( div, writer, { label: 'widget label' } );
                }
            } ) );

        editor.conversion.for( 'editingDowncast' )
            .add( downcastElementToElement( {
                model: 'myWidget',
                view: ( modelItem, writer ) => {
                    const div = writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'widget' } );

                    return toWidget( div, writer, { label: 'widget label' } );
                }
            } ) );

        editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' )
            .add( upcastElementToElement( {
                view: {
                    name: 'div',
                    class: 'widget'
                },
                model: 'myWidget'
            } ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the [widget API](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/widget.html) for that:

```
import Widget from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/widget';
import { toWidget } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/utils';
import { downcastElementToElement } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/downcast-converters';
import { upcastElementToElement } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/upcast-converters';

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Widget, /* ... other plugins ... */ ],
        toolbar: [ 'undo', 'redo' ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        window.editor = editor;

        const model = editor.model;

        model.schema.register( 'myWidget', {
            inheritAllFrom: '$block',
            isObject: true
        } );

        editor.conversion.for( 'dataDowncast' )
            .add( downcastElementToElement( {
                model: 'myWidget',
                view: ( modelItem, writer ) => {
                    return writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'widget' } );
                }
            } ) );

        editor.conversion.for( 'editingDowncast' )
            .add( downcastElementToElement( {
                model: 'myWidget',
                view: ( modelItem, writer ) => {
                    const div = writer.createContainerElement( 'div', { class: 'widget' } );

                    return toWidget( div, writer, { label: 'widget label' } );
                }
            } ) );

        editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' )
            .add( upcastElementToElement( {
                view: {
                    name: 'div',
                    class: 'widget'
                },
                model: 'myWidget'
            } ) );

        editor.setData(
            '<p>foobar</p>' +
            '<div class="widget">Non editable text goes here</div>' +
            '<p>foobar</p>'
        );
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
```

The key point is to use the [`toWidget()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_widget_utils.html#static-function-toWidget) function when downcasting an element to the editing view. Also, that element should be marked as an object in the [schema](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#schema).

Also don't forget to load the `Widget` plugin which turns on the support for widgets.

Comment: That almost works. I can't place my cursor there by clicking so it looks like i can't edit it. But if I move the cursor to the start of the editable area and then move it to the left, and press the backspace button the entire text is deleted. And in Firefox 61.0.1 i can set the cursor in the center of the foobar text, and then use the up key, to move the cursor up to the end of the non editable text. I still can't edit it, but I can use backspace to delete it.  But it's good enough for my use case so thanks.

Comment: Making it non-deletable is something more than making it non-editable. There are dozens of ways to delete things so it's not that easy. But if you could ask a separate question about it, I'd be glad to give it a try. CKEditor 5's differ and post-fixers should make it quite doable and reliable.

Comment: Where can I get a guide to creating a widget in CKEDITOR 5? I would like to move my project to this version and everything depends on the widget functionality. However, all I can find are little bits of code here and there and not any definitive guide or large code sample. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your steps without success..

**For better knowledge** (this guideline it's tested only in custom build for angular application but i think thats work everywhere)

probably you need use this command for follow correctly this guideline

> npm install -g webpack

and in add to this you need install globally another dependency but i don't remember what is! (you can easly search the error on google for find it)

1. Create your custom build [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)
2. unzip, open folder and run `npm install`
3. install widget(with type def. if necessary) and core dependencies

> npm i --save -D @ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget

> npm i --save -D @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-widget

> npm i --save -D @ckeditor/ckeditor5-core

4. go into path src/ckeditor.js and add the following code for create the reinmar [custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52299163/12777955)

```js
import {toWidget, Widget} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget";
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';

class NotEditable extends Plugin {
  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;

    const model = editor.model;
    model.schema.register('myWidget', {
      inheritAllFrom: '$block',
      isObject: true
    });

    editor.conversion.for('dataDowncast')
      .elementToElement({
        model: 'myWidget',
        view: (modelItem, writer) => {
          return writer.writer.createContainerElement('div', {class: 'widget'});
        }
      });

    editor.conversion.for('editingDowncast')
      .elementToElement({
        model: 'myWidget',
        view: (modelItem, writer) => {
          const div = writer.writer.createContainerElement('div', {class: 'widget'});
          return toWidget(div, writer.writer, {label: 'widget label'});
        }
      });

    editor.conversion.for('upcast')
      .elementToElement({
        view: {name: 'div', class: 'widget'},
        model: 'myWidget'
      });
  }
}
```

and in `Editor.builtinPlugins` add **Widget** and **NotEditable**

```js
Editor.builtinPlugins = [
  //***other plugin,
  Widget,
  NotEditable
];
```

5. exec in the terminal `npm run build`
6. copy the build folder into your project and import the build (follow official Ckeditor5 guideline for this) {in my case i follow this guideline in angular [guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/frameworks/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build)}

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem yesterday that when having a html table inside the isObject widget content, the table was still editable and also had controls.

The only way to fix it was to disable interaction inside my widget via css.

```css
.ck-widget.my-wdiget *:not(.ck.ck-reset_all.ck-widget__type-around) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

`.ck.ck-reset_all.ck-widget__type-around` is the class of the widget controls to add a linebreak before or after the widget. They are still usable.

Answer (score 0):

the codes above helped for this problem. I made a way to delete it completely like this, maybe it will help you. good luck

```
    editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {
                console.log( 'The data has changed!' );
                // we find the number of elements in the editor that have the simple-box class
                var firstBoxCount = document.getElementsByClassName("simple-box-title ck-widget").length;
                console.log("firstBoxCount",firstBoxCount);
                var simpleBoxCount = editor.getData().match(/simple-box-title/g).length;
                console.log("simpleBoxCount",simpleBoxCount);

                if(simpleBoxCount<firstBoxCount){
                    alert("Please do not delete templates. ")
                    // reverse the reverse kmut,
                    editor.execute('undo');

                }
            } );
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation `isReadOnly : Boolean`
Set it to true.
[Official Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-isReadOnly)