# Prevent widget from being dragged/moved in Ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

How do I prevent a widget from being dragged/moved in Ckeditor 5 ?

Normally I might just use the css: { pointer-events: none; } but the twist is that I need to be able to detect clicking on the widget.

The use case is that we have a few constant elements in the editor, which can't be edited or moved, and the only way I found to do that was to use a widget.

My code is based on this: [Create non editable block with text in CKEditor 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298444/create-non-editable-block-with-text-in-ckeditor-5)